# HorizontalScrollView: CustomAdapter with getView() doesn't reuse convertViews like ListView

Tags: android, android-adapter, horizontalscrollview

In one of my past projects I implemented a "Time Picker Carousel". It is based on a `HorizontalScrollView`. The user can pick a time while scrolling this view. The time value is calculated from the X-Offset of the `HorizontalScrollView`.

[image]

I wanted to share this project at github, but while cleaning up the code I realized some **bad performance** issue.

The `HorizontalScrollView` is populated with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The `getView()` uses a `Holder` for the `convertView`. I thought it might work as an adapter within a `ListView`, so only the visible items are rendered and reused if they will be destroyed. Instead, **all items are rendered!!! (in my case 1008!)** I add them myself (#1 in Code example), but even if I try to add less, the logic from remove (and recycle) old ones doesn't work, or did I miss something?

So my basic question is: **What do I have to change to make my adapter behave like `ListView`?**

1. I found [this so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020114/how-to-implement-view-recycling-mechanism-for-pager-adapter) and tried overriding `remove` function, but this is never called (somehow logic, because i am only adding)
2. There's a good [PagerAdapter example](https://gist.github.com/wang2bo2/4551304) at github, but somehow I cannot translate this to `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Any thoughts, links are welcome!

And please don't suggest using `ListView` instead. We decided to use `HorizontalScrollView` because of callbacks and the fact we already have a `ListView` in the layout.

**HorizontalScrollView**

```
InfiniteTimeScrubberHorizontalView extends HorizontalScrollView{
...
public void setAdapter(Context context, TimeScrubberListAdapter mAdapter) {
    this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    try {
        fillViewWithAdapter(mAdapter);
    } catch (ZeroChildException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void fillViewWithAdapter(TimeScrubberListAdapter mAdapter) {
    //...

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
    parent.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        //#1: Here: ALL views are added
        parent.addView(mAdapter.getView(i, null, parent));   
    }
}
```

**Adpater**

```
public class TimeScrubberListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

//...
private ArrayList<String> list;  //list from 0:00,0:30...23:00,23:30
final static int MAXIMUM_DAYS = 21

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size() * MAXIMUM_DAYS;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position % list.size());
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout layout;

    if (convertView == null) {
        layout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(context, layoutId, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.epg_item_text);
        layout.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        view = layout;
        holder = (Holder) layout.getTag();
    }

    layout.setLayoutParams(mLP);        

    String timeValue = getItem(position);
    holder.title.setText(timeValue);            

    return layout;
}
//...
@Override
public void remove(String object) {
    //not called...some how logic, because i do not remove an item
    super.remove(object);    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using some implementation of HorizontalListView?

Comment: Well, at the beginning we decided to use a `ScrollView` instead of `HorizontalListView`...but I will try out if I cannot find a solution for my current problem

Comment: maybe try adding in something like: if(convertView == null && convertView.isVisible()) . Please note this is a shot in the dark. Hope it helps

Comment: I suggest you take a look at how view recycling is implemented in listview.

Comment: Have you checked RecyclerView? https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html cames with Android L, but you can backport it..look at this s.o. post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440852/how-to-import-recyclerview-for-android-l-preview

Comment: @longilong ..plz share github url of ur project bcz i also need same requirement ..Thanks in Adavance

Comment: @girishce26 cannot share the project, but `RecyclerView` is your friend. to calculate the time, you find some infos here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507715/android-how-to-get-the-current-x-offset-of-recyclerview

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think maybe you are confusing where the logic lies for rendering between View and Adapter. Using an Adapter does not cause view recycling behavior. It is the `ListView` itself, along with its parent, `AbsListView`, that implement the view recycling behavior. The Adapter is required by the `ListView` in order to properly populate the Views that are shown on screen as needed, but the logic for actually choosing which Views to display and when and how to recycle those views is not in the Adapter at all.

If you look at the source code for [`HorizontalScrollView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.java) and for [`ListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java), you will see that they are dramatically different. They are not just the same thing in different orientations.

So, the long and short of it is that you will not be able to get the view recycling that you are looking for by using a `HorizontalScrollView` or even a simple descendent. If you want view recycling, you should check out the [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, still looking for a recycle solution for scrollview

Comment: @longilong Good luck with that. Recycling views is not trivial, nor can it be simply hacked onto a ScrollView.

Comment: ok ok, maybe i ll open pandoras box another day, thanks for your comments! ;)

Answer (score 2):

ScrollView keeps all child views in memory, so performance issue is common while using them.

Why not use some open source HorizontalListView library.
On searching I got these two libs out of which i have used first one in one of my projects and it worked smoothly without any memory issues.

- [Android-HorizontalListView](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView)
- [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView)

These libs are horizontal implementation of ListView, which does recycling of items for you based on which views are visible on screen. **Scrollview is bad choice for inifinite scrolling view.**

**UPDATE**: Now we have [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) from Android itself, which supports horizontal scrolling as well, it also enforces the use of **[Viewholder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html)** pattern

Comment: https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView not working for bitmaps ....can u help ?